# OpenShift: How to upload a directory?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am using OpenShift with Tomcat 7. I am trying to scp a directory into webapps. I search online and the recursion option is -r. However, when I type rhc help scp, the -r option is

> -r, --remote-path file_path              Remote filesystem path

So is there a recursion option for scp in OpenShift? How can I upload a directory in OpenShift?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scp localfile gearnumber@myapp.rhcloud.com:app-root/data

scp localdir -r gearnumber@myapp.rhcloud.com:app-root/data
```

The only directory where your user has write permission is `app-root/data`, you can reference it from your code with the environment variable `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`

Comment: I want to upload a directory, not just a file. I have already tried rhc scp with a file and it works. However, there is an error message when I tried with directories. The message says I need to use recursion.

Comment: scp can copy file and directories, what you mean is that it can recursively copy  within the directory you specified

Comment: How to I make scp able to "recursively copy within the directory"?

Comment: I think `gearnumber` should be replaced with `app-id` from `.git/config`, and the hostname should be `APPNAME-DOMAINNAME.rhcloud.com`, with the placeholder values taken from the `[rhc]` section of `.git/config`.

Comment: I would really like to see this approach but I'm not too confident in bash, please go on.

My answer is kind of best fit (IMO) because you could have more gears running (app, database,...) and hence the `gearnumber`

Comment: scp localdir -r gearnumber@myapp.rhcloud.com:app-root/data does NOT work on my iMac. But sip -r localdir gearnumber@myapp.rhcloud.com:app-root/data does. The -r has to be directly after the sap command.

Comment: But scp -r localdir gearnumber@myapp.rhcloud.com:app-root/data does. The -r has to be directly after the scp command.